# Import XLS data to MySQL table keeping 1st column as PK

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I've been given an Excel spreadsheet to be imported into a MySQL db.
Each Excel row has a number of columns of which the 1st is the PK and the rest are values that should be entered as separate rows into the DB. Example:

```
| SizeGroup | Size1 | Size2 | Size3 | Size4 | Size5 |
=====================================================
|     A     |   S   |   M   |   L   |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     B     |   S   |   M   |   L   |  XL   |       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     C     |   S   |   M   |  XXL  |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     D     |   36  |   37  |  38   |  39   |  40   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     E     |   M   |   XL  |       |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     F     |   39  |   40  |   41  |   42  |  43   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The desired result would be:

```
Table: sizes
id | size_group | size
=======================
 1 |      A     |  S
-----------------------
 2 |      A     |  M
-----------------------
 3 |      A     |  L
-----------------------
 4 |      B     |  S
-----------------------
 5 |      B     |  M
-----------------------
 6 |      B     |  L
-----------------------
 7 |      B     |  XL
-----------------------
```

How can this be achieved? I could write some code in PHP using a library for reading through the xls and writing to the db but there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can import excel sheet in Mysql like below:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

After import data , specify primarykey like below:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY(colname);
```